# cs50 speller stuck!! Please tell me why i am getting Signal 11(SIGSEGV): dumping core

Tags: c, cs50

I am completely stuck with this segmentation fault. Can't even test if my code will actually do what's intended. Anyone can please help?

I am getting segmentation fault at the line: table[hashed] = n;
(Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core.
Bad permissions for mapped region at address.....)

Here is my code.Many Thanks!

````
// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 1327;

// Hash table
node *table[sizeof(node) * N];
int loadedsize = 0;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    int hashed = hash(word);
    node *cursor = table[hashed]->next;
    while (cursor != NULL)
    {
        if(strcasecmp(word, cursor->word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            cursor = cursor->next;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // TODO: Improve this hash function
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= strlen(word); i++)
    {
        sum += (tolower(word[i]) * (15 - i));
    }
    sum = sum % 1327;
    return sum;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    //setup variable for word
    char s[LENGTH + 1];

    //NULL table
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        table[i] = NULL;
    }

    //setup new node
    node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (n == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //open file
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (dict == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //read words and place node in table
    while (fscanf(dict, "%s", s) != EOF)
    {
        int hashed = hash(s);
        strcpy(n->word, s);
        n->next = NULL;
        if (table[hashed] == NULL)
        {
            table[hashed] = n;
        }
        else
        {
            n->next = table[hashed];
            table[hashed] = n;    <<<<THIS IS WHERE I GET DUMPING CORE>>>>
        }
        loadedsize += 1;
    }
    free(n);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return loadedsize;
}

```
````

Comment: Well, I can tell you `node *table[sizeof(node) * N];` is wrong. The table is supposed to contain `N` slots for `N` pointers. You're *way* oversizing it. Add to that, `node *cursor = table[hashed]->next;` is a recipe for disaster, since initially the table contains `N` null pointers (if, indeed, `table` is somewhere in global space, which we're not certain of because you provided no [mcve]). And.. you're allocating *one* node, then using it for *ever* insertion, **and** then deleting the node, so now all you have is a table full of the same dangling pointer. Get the to a debugger; pronto.

Comment: The `while (fscanf(dict, "%s", s) != EOF)` loop is using the *same* `n` node for every single word. No chance that will work.

Comment: To fix what kaylum found, you need to put the `malloc` _inside_ your loop. That is, move your `malloc` call [and `NULL` check] to the top of your `while (fscanf(...)) != EOF) {` loop body (i.e. just before the `strcpy(n->word, s);` line). That way each new word gets a new/unique `struct` instance.

Comment: I don't think you should try to write the entire program in one go. Instead, write it in stages. For example, you could start by writing a hash table and make sure you can perform the operations you are going to need, like load and find. Then you can write another program to read and print the dictionary (don't try and store anything). Finally you can combine the programs. At each stage try and write code for only one new thing at a time. That way, you have an idea where the problem is likely to be.